# How to filter multiple date ranges in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am having issues filtering multiple date ranges. For example I want to make a image collection that also includes the same months from 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023 etc. What's the best way to do this?

```
//1 Mask Clouds
function maskS2clouds(sentColl) {
  var qa = sentColl.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return sentColl.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
//2. Define Sentinel-2 Image Collection
var sentColl = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-08-31')
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10)
  .filterBounds(AOI)
  //.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'])
  .map(maskS2clouds);

print(sentColl);

//4. Compute the median in each band and each pixel and then select RGBI bands. Band names are B2_Median, B3_Median etc.
var imgMed = sentColl.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
  .select('B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B8_median');
//5. Output image. Add it to map.
var VisualizeP = {
  bands: ['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median'],
  min: 0.012,
  max: 0.145,
  gamma: 1.30,
};
//Map.addLayer(imgMed,VisualizeP);
Map.centerObject(AOI, 10);

//Clip image
var NS_Sent_2019 = imgMed.clip(AOI)
Map.addLayer(NS_Sent_2019, VisualizeP);
//6. Export image 
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: imgMed,
  description: 'Y2019',
  scale: 5,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use an `ee.Filter.calendarRange()`. One option is to start by quickly filter down the images to the years you're interested in, using a regular `filterDate()`, then apply the calander range filter.

```
ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
  .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2023-09-01')
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6, 8, 'month'))
```